# Accessing Json array in EJS file script tag

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to access a JSON array inside the script tag of a EJS file.
I'm passing the JSON array from my index.js file to the EJS file while rendering it. The code is:

```
sampleJArr=["data1","data2","data3"];
app.get('/test', function(req,res){
res.render('testfile',{
 'mJsonArr': sampleJArr
});
```

In the EJS file (testfile.ejs), code-:

```
<div>
  <!--Printing the JSON array. It prints  -->
  <p>JSON.stringify(mJsonArr)</p>
  <button onClick="myFunc">Take test</button>
</div>
<script>
  function myFunc(){
    var JsonData= <%= mJsonArr[0] %>
    console.log(JsonData)
  }
</script>
```

Error:-Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

But when I'm trying to do a console("some string") inside myFunc then it's not giving that error. Only when I'm accessing mJsonArr inside the script tag, I'm getting UncaughtRefrence error. How can I access the passed mJsonArr inside my script tag ? Please contribute. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can not access mJsonArr[0] in your script tag is because EJS just replace `<%= mJsonArr[0] %>` to `data1` which means your generated html will be like

```
<div>
  <!--Printing the JSON array. It prints  -->
  <p>JSON.stringify(mJsonArr)</p>
  <button onClick="myFunc">Take test</button>
</div>
<script>
  function myFunc(){
    var JsonData= data1
    console.log(JsonData)
  }
</script>
```

In which there are 2 points are wrong

1. onClick="myFunc"

This need to be changed to onClick="myFunc()". Otherwise it will never invoke.

2. var JsonData= data1

This is not assigning a **string value 'data1'** to variable. It is assigning a value of a **variable named 'data1'** to variable JsonData.

The correct way to do this should be

```
<div>
  <!--Printing the JSON array. It prints  -->
  <p>JSON.stringify(mJsonArr)</p>
  <button onClick="myFunc()">Take test</button>
</div>
<script>
  function myFunc(){
    var JsonData= '<%= mJsonArr[0] %>'
    console.log(JsonData)
  }
</script>
```

Hope it can help you

Comment: Thanks man, it worked perfectly. I got your explanation too :)

Comment: Glad I can help. If possible please mark my answer as correct